# Touch Icon For android

Tags: android, apple-touch-icon

I was checking this blog http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons and it worked fine for iPhone , but for Android I get a weird Icon on home screen.
Snapshot of Page I was viewing and in the bottom left a tiny touch icon that I added in headers.
Why is this so Is it possible to get it like a touch icon in my android device(2.2) as well ?

Answer (score 0):

This [favicon compatibility test](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility) indicates the following regarding Android:

- Samsung Galaxy S (Android 2.3.3): the default browser takes the 16x16 PNG icon (so not the Apple Touch icon) and adds some decoration around it. Although correct, this is not the expected behavior.
- HTC Desire (Android 2.2.2): the default browser takes the 57x57 Apple Touch icon, which is correct.
- Nexus 7 (Android 4.4):

  - Chrome takes the 152x152 Apple Touch icon, which is correct.
  - Firefox takes the 196x196 PNG picture, which is a bit surprising but correct, too.

In the end, you might observe some unexpected behaviors on old Android devices.

In order to maximize compatibility and avoid playing with Photoshop&friends, HTML code and devices, you can try this [favicon generator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/). Some extensive testing has been performed already. Full disclosure: I am the author of this site.